# ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATION without renaming

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I am writing a Google Chrome extension with the help of Google closure compiler.
I make heavy use of the message API to communicate between code that runs on different processes. Thats why my files need to be compiled separately. If I use advanced optimizations I also have to access properties with quoted strings in data I send with this message API. That works without a problem but it makes my code look ugly. But I like the dead code removal that comes with advanced optimizations.

I would like to be able to do dead code removal without the renaming that comes with advanced optimizations. Is this possible with the closure compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is [not possible out of the box](http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/issues/detail?id=183&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Component%20Owner%20Summary), You can however download the source and make the customization yourself in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I agree.  It is ugly to have to use `obj["prop"]` instead of `obj.prop` in all your code that deals with data being passed around just to use the Closure Compiler in Advanced mode.

One trick I have developed is to build a mapping object:

```
var mapping = {
  field1: "field1",
  field2: "field2"
    :
};
```

This object, after compiling by the Closure Compiler, will have field names mangled (renamed) mapping to the original, unmangled names, e.g:

```
var a = {
   b: "field1",
   c: "field2"
      :
};
```

Then before I send the data, I pass it through a function that clones the entire data structure, converting each mangled field name into the unmangled version in the new object before passing the *new* object out:

```
function cloneData(obj) {
    var newobj = {};
    foreach (var name in obj) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(name)) continue;
        var fullname = mapping[name] || name;
        newobj[fullname] = obj[name];
    }
    return newobj;
}
```

For data received, do the reverse.

Comment: Nice trick. I did something similar. Though after a while I decided to drop Closure in favor of plain old javascript. I was developing just for Chrome (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kfimchjilnmjmjpdgedcamjninpdkkpk) And a javascript library seemed a bit overkill for me.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how many you want to hold onto, you might look into the ["Export Symbols You Want To Keep"](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3.html#mixed) section of the docs.

Comment: It is stated clearly in my question that I'm already exporting (...access properties with quoted strings...) the properties of my messages. I am specifically looking for the dead code removal without renaming. Since I don't have to transfer the source over the wire I don't really care too much about minifying. However, I do care about the clean resulting code without 10000 lines of dead code. I will add an answer myself so I can keep my reputation if no one can come up with a relevant answer, other than 'It doesn't work'.